# readline hangs on manual pipe()

Tags: perl, posix

I'm trying to dispel the magic fork variant of open:

```
# magic-fork.pl
if (open my $fh, '-|') { # fork self, make new fd for reading, attach child STDOUT to it
    STDOUT->say('parent getpid: ', $$);
    STDOUT->say('parent STDOUT->fileno: ', STDOUT->fileno);
    STDOUT->say('parent $fh->fileno: ', $fh->fileno);
    while (my $line = $fh->getline) {
        STDOUT->print('parent readline from child: ', $line);
    }
} else {
    STDOUT->say('child getpid: ', $$);
    STDOUT->say('child STDOUT->fileno: ', STDOUT->fileno);
}
```

It runs and finishes.

```
# plain-fork.pl
pipe my $r, my $w;
if (fork) {
    STDOUT->say('parent getpid: ', $$);
    STDOUT->say('parent STDOUT->fileno: ', STDOUT->fileno);
    STDOUT->say('parent $r->fileno: ', $r->fileno);
    STDOUT->say('parent $w->fileno: ', $w->fileno);
    while (my $line = $r->getline) {
        STDOUT->print('parent readline from child: ', $line);
    }
} else {
    $w->say('child getpid: ', $$);
    $w->say('child $r->fileno: ', $r->fileno);
    $w->say('child $w->fileno: ', $w->fileno);
    $w->say('child STDOUT->fileno: ', STDOUT->fileno);
}
```

This program unexpectedly hangs in the loop.

I tried to no avail:

- calling $w->autoflush(1)
- explicit close on handles
- explicit exit
- POSIX::dup2 $w onto STDOUT
- checking strace -ff to see whether I missed a crucial syscall

What's the problem?

Comment: I believe Shawn's answer is correct; reading continues to block because the pipe is still open for writing (by the parent).  But you do say you tried explicitly closing handles; did you try closing the write handle in the parent (before the getline)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `pipe` before `fork`ing (Like usual for this sort of IPC), so both processes have open copies of both the read and write file descriptors, so the read loop in the parent will just block waiting for more input which never comes from the still-open write end.

The child process needs to `close $r;`, the parent process needs to `close $w;` at the start of their respective blocks (Or after you print out the file descriptors for those handles).

Comment: Key piece of missing info: The pipe will only return EOF once there are no open handles to the write end of the pipe.